# Are there any pitfalls to using member references to members?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Lately I've come up with the following hack:

```
template<typename T> class Vector<4,T>
{
public:
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
    T w;
    Vector<2,T>& upperLeft=*((Vector<2,T>*)(&x));
    Vector<2,T>& lowerRight = *((Vector<2, T>*)(&z));
 /*rest of class */
 }
```

Should I expect any hidden issues to byte my rear end in the future from that code?

Edit:
This is what Vector<2,T> looks like:

```
template<typename T> class Vector<2,T>
{
public:
    T x;
    T y;
/*methods*/
}
```

Comment: YES. x is not a Vector<2,T>, it is a T. So uh. This will segfault most likely. It is not even possible for T to be a Vector<2,T> cuz then it would be a Vector<2,Vector<2,Vector<2....

Comment: @Well, a Vector<2,T> is nothing more than a Vector<4,T> with two elements, there having the same length and memory layout as half of Vector4.

Comment: Then it may be ok, or it may not, depending if you have any virtual functions in the class. If not, then it'll work. If this is the behavior you want, though, you should be use unions instead.

Comment: Besides what's already been mentioned, this also adds 4 or 8 bytes to every `Vector<4>` instance. Better just create a method to return a `Vector<2, T>`; copying two floats or doubles is really not that expensive.

Comment: @Thomas (it'd also be in-lined by any compiler that's worth using, so it would be free.)

Comment: @Thomas The problem is that I also want to write to the values, using my convoluted hack.

Comment: Return a `Vector<2, T&>` from your accessor, with the two `T& x, y` bound to the fields in the `Vector<4, T>` appropriately.  See `tuple` and `tie`.

Answer (score 2):

Oh god

Yes. You're relying on undefined behavior at the moment. In addition to relying on the exact layout of two classes (packing may bite you here), you're also relying on type-punning. This violates strict aliasing and, aside from being UB, you may not have changes to X or Y reflect in your upperleft member.

That said, between packing `#pragma`s and whatever Visual Studio's version of `-fno-strict-aliasing` is, you might be able to rely on it working given a specific version of the compiler with specific optimization/layout/etc flags. But this code is going to be extremely compiler specific.